# Cygwin crashing when building gmp library

Tags: cygwin, gmp

I'm trying to build the gmp library using cygwin. At a point in the configure process, it crashes, telling me that

> no usable M4 in $PATH or /usr/5bin

I think that this means it is looking for MinGW, under which MSYS and M4 exist. I have verified that my path variable contains

> c:\mingw\msys

which is where I believe M4 exists, no? Can anyone help me figure out why this is crashing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. I found it in the cygwin setup under Interpreters. Thanks anyway!